# Converting 10 minute data to hourly average using if condition in R

Tags: r, average

Similar questions may be asked before.I'm new to R and unable to use the other methods.I have one month 10 minute interval data.Example is below. First column is date second is hour.

```
> 01  00 10 2,8     
  01  00 20 2,4     
  01  00 30 2,4     
  01  00 40 2,1     
  01  00 50 2,3     
  01  01 00 1,9     
  01  01 10 2
```

I tried to write a code that calculates hourly average if first column(day) and second column(hour) is equal. Because of some values are missing. I tried this code but it does not help.

```
for(i in 1:4314) {
    if(mydata1[i,1] == mydata1[i+1,1] && (mydata1[i,2]= mydata1[i+1,2])){
        while(mydata1[i,2] != mydata1[i+1,2]){sum(mydata1[i,4])}}
    else {
        print(mean(sum(mydata1[i,4])))
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy with the `dplyr` package.
Let's give your data some names:

```
names(mydata) = c("day", "hour", "minute", "value")

library(dplyr)
group_by(mydata, day, hour) %>%
  summarize(hourly.mean = mean(hour))
```